# Expression in bash scripts

Tags: shell

I have a simple bash script

```
v1=10
v2=20
val='expr $v1 + $v2'
echo "the sum is: $val"
```

the output is :
"the sum is expr $v1 + $v2"

but it shoud be 30!

I have another question:
if i write another bash like below:

```
echo "the equality is `[ $v1 == 10 ]`"
```

it doesn't prompt anything
echo "the equality is"

Comment: The open square bracket is the test command; it does not output something printable, but it sets the exit status. Try this at prompt: `[ 1 = 1 ]; echo $?` (and try different values also).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try backticks.  the third line should be like this:

```
val=`expr $v1 + $v2`
```

for more see: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: thanks for the response I asked another question, can you answer it as well?

Answer (score 0):

See the live example here: https://rextester.com/HKLJT47293

```
v1=10
v2=20
echo the sum is expr $((v1 + v2))
```